# Persistent session between routes express-sessions NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, express-session

I am not able to keep sessions between different routers with express-sessions. This is my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const myRoutes = require('./routes/my-route');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'SECRET',
    cookie: {maxAge: 60*60*1000, httpOnly: true, secure: false},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.use('/my-routes', myRoutes);
app.use('/submit', function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.info = req.body.info;
});
```

Any calls to `/submit` work fine, and the session is maintained. But when I try to call anything with `/my-routes/<route>`, a new cookie is created and the session is reset.

Before any calls this is what the session looks like

```
{
  "cookie": {
    "originalMaxAge":3600000,
    "expires":"2018-06-08T17:51:37.229Z",
    "secure":false,
    "httpOnly":true,
    "path":"/"
  }
}
```

After a single call to `/submit`

```
{
  "cookie": {
    "originalMaxAge":3600000,
    "expires":"2018-06-08T17:51:37.229Z",
    "secure":false,
    "httpOnly":true,
    "path":"/"
  },
  "info": "thing"
}
```

Then, when I call any route in `/my-routes/<route>`

```
{
  "cookie": {
    "originalMaxAge":3600000,
    "expires":"2018-06-08T17:51:37.446Z",
    "secure":false,
    "httpOnly":true,
    "path":"/"
  }
}
```

which looks as thought the cookie was reset because of the new expires.

This is how I am calling the ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/submit',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    window.location.href = '/index.html';
  },
});
```

Comment: You really ought to show the implementation of `my-routes` but my guess is it's creating a new router?

Comment: @James at the moment it's just printing to the console with `router.get('<path>', function)`

Comment: @TwoShorts try adding this.. req.session.save(function(err) {
  // session saved
})

Comment: @James it returns with no error and still does not work

Comment: @TwoShort wasn&#39;t my suggestion :) although you should get into the habit of calling `save` as it&amp;amp;#39;ll be necessary when you move to a persistent session store (won't be the issue here). Could you elaborate on your test scenario and show *all* the associated code.